# Javascript copy node and modify HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a node cloned, like so:

```
var my_ele = document.getElementsByClassName('my-ele')[0].cloneNode(true)
```

Which copies:

```
<div class="my-ele">
    <h1>My Element</h1>
    <p>Some text...</p>
</div>
```

Once copied, how can I modify the HTML of the copied node? Maybe add in another heading and move the paragraph to the top. Is that achievable in Javascript?

Comment: Simple, once this element gets added to DOM you can easily manipulate it using the standard techniques available.

Comment: my_ele.innerHTML = //just write whatever html you want it to contain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use .innerHTML.

```
// copy the node
var my_ele = document.getElementsByClassName('my-ele')[0].cloneNode(true);

// set the innerHTML value of the copied node to whatever you want. 
// Here, we're appending a red H1 to the beginning of it.
my_ele.innerHTML = '<h1 style="color:red;">Another Header</h1>' + my_ele.innerHTML;

// append to the dom
document.body.appendChild(my_ele);
```

Live example: http://jsbin.com/tohamuqehe/edit?html,js,console,output

**EDIT**

to re-order the elements, you could further break down your cloned element into its children elements, manipulate them individually, and then re-append to the cloned element. Example: http://jsbin.com/buvocajisu/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Would it be possible to re-order any of the cloned elements?

Comment: @Doidgey sure, please see the edit / attached jsbin.